# Using Libdl.dlopen kills Julia

Tags: c, dll, julia

I am trying to call a C code from Julia v0.6.2, Windows 10.

Here is the C code I compiled into a DLL with [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) gcc.

```
int timesTwo(int x) {
    return 2*x;
}
```

The compile commands:

```
gcc -c mydll.c
gcc -shared -o mydll.dll mydll.o
```

I tested the DLL with a test C program and it works. Then I tried to call it with Julia using an absolute path to the DLL.

```
using Base.Libdl
x = Int32(2)
mylib = dlopen("C:\\Users\\pedro\\Documents\\codigos\\exampleDLL\\C\\mydll.dll")
ccall((:timesTwo, mylib), Int32, (Int32,), x)
```

Then the Julia's Workspace is restarted (all variables become undefined as soon as I use the command `dlopen`).

What is happening and how can I solve it?

---

### Update

That must be a windows issue. Could not reproduce in an Ubuntu distro.

Comment: maybe you should add `-fPIC` flag and try again.

Comment: `int double( int x )...` even *compiles*?!?!  [`double` is a reserved word](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword).

Comment: the actual function was named `ddouble`. Changed it to `timesTwo` to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use the same compiler that Julia uses (with the -fPIC flag) to build your DLL. On Windows, julia is actually build with the 
Cygwin-to-MinGW cross-compiler:

https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/README.windows.md#cygwin-to-mingw-cross-compiling

Can you install the mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core package (for just the C compiler) and use the x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc compiler command (instead of gcc) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-fPIC` switch to generate the position independent code. Plus, you might be lying to `Julia` unless your `int` is defined as `int32` on the specific platform. To be sure, you need to change `ccall((:timesTwo, mylib), Int32, (Int32,), x)` to `ccall((:timesTwo, mylib), Cint, (Cint,), x)`. Finally, to make the code work for any operating system, please consider replacing `mylib = dlopen("C:\\Users\\pedro\\Documents\\codigos\\exampleDLL\\C\\mydll.dll")` to `const mylib = dlopen(joinpath(pwd(), "mydll.dll"))`. `const` is there for efficiency reasons, `joinpath` is OS-agnostic, meaning that it will add forward slash for *nix-based systems. Later on, when you want to change the library to `.so`, for instance, you should not deal with slashes, too.